# I want rescale my newsletter HMTL code to fit any screen when i send email

Tags: css, html-email

When I send the HTML email, the result is bigger than the screen. Is there anyway I can make it fit on any type of screen?

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>NEWS LETTER</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style>

     
           body{
                -webkit-transform:scale(0.67);
       -moz-transform:scale(0.67);
       -ms-transform:scale(0.67);
       transform:scale(0.5);
       -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
       -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
       -moz-transform-origin:0 0;
       transform-origin:0 0;
               
    }
            
           table{
                -webkit-transform:scale(0.67);
       -moz-transform:scale(0.67);
       -ms-transform:scale(0.67);
       transform:scale(0.5);
       -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
       -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
       -moz-transform-origin:0 0;
       transform-origin:0 0;
               
    }
           

        </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Save for Web Slices (NEWS LETTER.png) -->
    <table id="Table_01" width="1900"  height="3459" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" valign="top">
     <tr>
      <td colspan="16">
       <a href="http://www.centrale-casablanca.ma/">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Lb36PgA.jpg" width="1900" height="439" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/FzmJeIc.jpg" width="145" height="67" alt=""></td>
      <td colspan="2">
       <a href="https://twitter.com/centralecasa">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/pBfKQPz.jpg" width="66" height="67" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
      <td>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/We2fz1U.jpg" width="72" height="67" alt=""></td>
      <td>
       <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/3747130">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/We2fz1U.jpg" width="71" height="67" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
      <td>
       <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/centralecasablanca">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9A9A78U.jpg" width="71" height="67" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
      <td>
       <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ForumECC/?ref=page_internal">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/eeR6Rys.jpg" width="72" height="67" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
      <td colspan="2">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/UOEz98z.jpg" width="70" height="67" alt=""></td>
      <td colspan="7">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/6H7AABM.jpg" width="1333" height="67" alt=""></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="16">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/B6WReG6.jpg" width="1900" height="613" alt=""></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
       <a href="http://www.centrale-casablanca.ma/lecole">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ixN7WX6.jpg" width="192" height="64" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
      <td colspan="6">
       <a href="http://www.centrale-casablanca.ma/formation-dingenieur">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vwHw3CE.jpg" width="349" height="64" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
      <td colspan="3">
       <a href="http://www.centrale-casablanca.ma/executive-education">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SWH3v3L.jpg" width="311" height="64" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
      <td>
       <a href="http://www.centrale-casablanca.ma/recherche">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/82sJQq3.jpg" width="185" height="64" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
      <td colspan="2">
       <a href="http://www.centrale-casablanca.ma/entreprise">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QxalLhP.jpg" width="371" height="64" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
      <td>
       <a href="http://www.centrale-casablanca.ma/mobilite">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/s6V5VYl.jpg" width="164" height="64" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
      <td>
       <a href="http://www.centrale-casablanca.ma/vie-sur-le-campus">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vwS1uNT.jpg" width="328" height="64" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="16">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/lCLygkp.jpg" width="1900" height="712" alt=""></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="10">
       <a href="http://www.centrale-casablanca.ma/lecole/concours-admissions/concours-sur-licence">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cevnIzl.jpg" width="764" height="90" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
      <td colspan="3">
       <a href="http://www.centrale-casablanca.ma/actualites">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/3A9aOad.jpg" width="560" height="90" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
      <td colspan="3">
       <a href="http://www.centrale-casablanca.ma/formation-dingenieur/cursus-de-lingenieur-centralien">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qS0M7Zh.jpg" width="576" height="90" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="16">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/iCsYxLh.jpg" width="1900" height="692" alt=""></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="10">
       <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ForumECC/?fref=ts">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/HsCa8EZ.jpg" width="764" height="87" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
      <td colspan="3">
       <a href="https://www.facebook.com/centract/?fref=ts">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/3A9aOad.jpg" width="560" height="87" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
      <td colspan="3">
                <a href="http://www.centrale-casablanca.ma/diaporama/conference-2">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dzkthaq.jpg" width="576" height="87" alt=""></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="16">
       <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzWF9ao5Ibw">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/mswVjLl.jpg" width="1900" height="694" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2VFp8N.jpg" width="145" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2VFp8N.jpg" width="47" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2VFp8N.jpg" width="19" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2VFp8N.jpg" width="72" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2VFp8N.jpg" width="71" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2VFp8N.jpg" width="71" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2VFp8N.jpg" width="72" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2VFp8N.jpg" width="44" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2VFp8N.jpg" width="26" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2VFp8N.jpg" width="197" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2VFp8N.jpg" width="88" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2VFp8N.jpg" width="185" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2VFp8N.jpg" width="287" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2VFp8N.jpg" width="84" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2VFp8N.jpg" width="164" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td>
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2VFp8N.jpg" width="328" height="1" alt=""></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
            </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

It gets resized on the navigator, but not when I send the email.

Comment: Email readers are very, very simple reading HTML and CSS. I would recomend you go without modern CSS styles. like the ones on the top of the document.

Comment: Yeah but the is a way to resize the email with the CSS without changing all the code ?

Comment: @SimoMansouri No. Get rid of the `transform:scale(0.5);` stuff and use more old-fashioned methods to resize, like giving the table `width="100%"` rather than a fixed width in pixels.